# django template iterated list: how create unique overlay-popup for each item?

Tags: css, django, django-templates

In django easy to generate an iterated list of titles from context received by template:

```py
{% for instance in object_list %}
<li>{{instance.international_title}} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

And in css easy to create a popup overlay:

```css
#overlay
{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
    border:5px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius:10px;
}
<div align="center">
    <a href="#overlay"> Click Title for Detail</a>
</div>
<div id="overlay">
<p> Here is the text giving more detail<p>
</div>
```

Would like to be able to associate a unique text with each unique title `{{instance.international_short_description}}` for the purposes of the overlay popup. However do not see how to do this. Is it necessary to somehow create a series of css classes: `#overlay1, #overlay2` with custom href to each one? Is it possible to use a single class, pass a variable to it and then select the correct text? Have not been able to find examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the id, for example by adding the primary key of the instance, like:

```
{% for instance in object_list %}
    <div align="center">
        <a href="#overlay{{ instance.pk }}">{{ instance.international_title }}</a>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay{{ instance.pk }}">
    <p>{{ instance.international_short_description }}<p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: OK that looks good. So would need to define the css class multiple times in the for loop as well #overlay{{ instance.pk }}
{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
    border:5px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius:10px;
}

Comment: @maker3478: no, instead of applying the css on an id, I suggest you make one for a class name and then add a `class="..."` to the HTML. Using an id, is usually only a good idea if you know there is only one item to which you want to apply that style.